# How to solve Two-Point Boundary Value Problem (Bratu-type equation)?

Tags: differential-equations

I reviewed [Q1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40262/unable-to-solve-two-point-boundary-value-problem) and [Q2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43469/initial-and-boundary-value-errors?rq=1), but I can not use of they. I wrote the following code:

```
eq = D[u[x], {x, 2}] - Pi^2*Exp[u[x]] == 0; 
init = {u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}; 
Eqe = Quiet[NDSolve[Join[eq, init], u[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

I do not know why it does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: First, it should be `Join[{eq}, init]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one hell of a simple `BVP`, which *Mathematica* does not handle with ease.

Here is my experimentation,

```
eq = u''[x] - Pi^2*Exp[u[x]] == 0;
init = {u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0};
```

First, I tried without specifying the method like the OP

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eq}, init], u[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.7071067304302846`, step size is effectively
>   zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

Then, with a method,

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eq}, init], u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", "StiffnessTest" -> False}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.7071067304302846`, step size is effectively
>   zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

**Shooting**

After trying different method's, finally I got lucky with shooting

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eq}, init], u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {u[0.0] == 0, u'[0.0] == 0}}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.7071067304302846`, step size is effectively
>   zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

The singularity seems to occur in the vicinity of `x=1`. So, I tried with different `StartingInitialConditions` and finally got able to produce an answer without any warning.

```
sol = NDSolve[Join[{eq}, init], u[x], {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {u[0.5] == 0, u'[0.5] == 0}}]
Plot[u[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

**Note**

This `BVP` can easily be solved with maple numerically,

```
restart;with(plots):
eq := diff(u(x),x$2)-Pi^2*exp(u(x));
ibcs:=(u)(0)=0,u(1)=0;
sol:=dsolve({eq,ibcs},numeric);
odeplot(sol,[[x,u(x)]],0..1,color=[red],axes=boxed);
```

[image]

Finally, comparing the solutions from both *Mathematica* and Maple

[image]

Comment: Many many thanks. In this way, output just is `plot`. Is the function of solution can be found with `Plot`?

Comment: @user45459 The output of `NDSolve` is an interpolating function not just a plot `InterpolatingFunction[data][x]`. `Plot` command is only used for plotting nothing else.

Comment: I am confused. Because I do not have any output. I want to have a function `u[x]` on `[0,1]`, but I gain Plot on `[0,1]`. Is there any way which I gain a function `u[x]` or a polynomial for interpolation function?

Comment: @user45459 Well, `NDSolve` produces numerical solution in terms of interpolation function. If you are looking for analytical solution then you should use `DSolve`? `DSolve[eq, u, x]`